# TypeORM joins by multiple PrimaryColumns ignoring defined JoinColumn

Tags: postgresql, join, entity, typeorm, primary-key

I have an entity called `Pack` with two PrimaryColumns - `idpack` and `idproduct`:

```
import {
  CreateDateColumn,
  Entity,
  JoinColumn,
  OneToMany,
  PrimaryColumn,
  PrimaryGeneratedColumn,
} from 'typeorm';

import { productospack } from './productospack.entity';

@Entity({
  schema: 'sch_main',
  name: 'packs',
})
export class packs {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  idpack: number;

  @PrimaryColumn('int')
  idproducto: number;

  @CreateDateColumn()
  creationdate: Date;

  @OneToMany(() => productospack, (productpack) => productpack.pack)
  @JoinColumn({ name: 'idpack' })
  productos: productospack[];
}
```

This entity has a OneToMany relation to another entity called PackProduct:

```
import {
  Column,
  Entity,
  JoinColumn,
  ManyToOne,
  PrimaryGeneratedColumn,
} from 'typeorm';
import { packs } from './pack.entity';

@Entity({
  schema: 'sch_main',
  name: 'productospack',
})
export class productospack {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  idproductopack: number;

  @Column('int')
  idpack: number;

  @Column('int')
  idproducto: number;

  @Column('int')
  productquantity: number;

  @ManyToOne(() => packs, (pack) => pack.productos)
  @JoinColumn({ name: 'idpack' })
  pack: packs;
}
```

I expected that when querying for a Pack, TypeORM would join the PackProduct table by idpack only, since I have defined @JoinColumn({name: 'idpack'}).

However, when executing the query, I see that TypeORM is joining on both idpack and idproduct columns:

```
INNER JOIN PackProduct 
ON PackProduct.idpack = Pack.idpack 
AND PackProduct.idpack = Pack.idproduct
```

This results in an invalid join, since I need it to join only by idpack.

I would expect TypeORM to respect the defined @JoinColumn and join only on that column, instead of joining on all PrimaryColumns.

I am using TypeORM version ^0.3.19 with PostgreSQL database.

I have tried explicitly defining the join column in the inverse side of the relationship as well but the behavior is the same.

Is this expected behavior when having multiple PrimaryColumns?

Or could it be considered a bug?

How can I make it join only on the defined @JoinColumn in this case?

Comment: Please ask 1 specific researched non-duplicate question. Either ask re 1 bad query/function with obligatory [mre], including why you think it should return something else or are unsure at the 1st subexpression where you don't get what you expect or are stuck, justified by reference to authoritative documentation, or ask about your overall goal giving working parts you can do with justification & a [mre]--then misunderstood code doesn't belong. But please ask about unexpected behaviour 1st because misconceptions get in the way of your goal. [ask] [Help] Basic questions are faqs.

Comment: A [mre] includes:  
Please in code questions give
Debug questions require a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code including initialization; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For SQL include DDL & tabular initialization code. For debug that includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK.(Debugging fundamental.)